# Material UI ItemList Trying to bring Icon closer to element

Tags: javascript, material-ui, material-design

Im trying to bring this - icon closer to the text but i'm not exactly sure how.

When I go into developer mode it shows me this. [image]

I don't know what the purplish stuff means. My end goal is to try to move the icon to the upper right corner of where the "Steve First" box is but I'm not sure how to do that. This is the code where i'm building my list.

```
<List style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", padding: 0 }}>
  <ListItem
    className={classes.removePerson}
    secondaryAction={
      <IconButton
        sx={{
          zIndex: "1",
          width: "15px !important",
          height: "15px !important"
        }}
      >
        <RemoveCircleIcon sx={{ fontSize: "20px" }} />
      </IconButton>
    }
  >
    <ListItemAvatar>
      <Avatar src="stuff.img" />
    </ListItemAvatar>
    <ListItemText
      className={classes.peopleListSpacing}
      primary="Steve First Steve First Steve First"
    />
  </ListItem>
  <ListItem
    className={classes.removePerson}
    secondaryAction={
      <IconButton
        sx={{
          zIndex: "1",
          width: "15px !important",
          height: "15px !important"
        }}
      >
        <RemoveCircleIcon sx={{ fontSize: "20px" }} />
      </IconButton>
    }
  >
    <ListItemAvatar>
      <Avatar src="stuff.img" />
    </ListItemAvatar>
    <ListItemText className={classes.peopleListSpacing} primary="Steve First" />
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

The code display this. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The purple space is available space that is not being utilized.

How about just making your ListItemAvatar a flex container and centering it? You might like to right align it, then just add some right margin.

Create a new `listItemAvatar` prop in your classes object.

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

```
<ListItemAvatar className={classes.listItemAvatar}>
  <Avatar src="..." />
</ListItemAvatar>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't do anything. What I want is the icon to get as close to the ListItemText as it can, but for some reason it doesn't fill the empty space.

Comment: @Shinne can you share your classes too? Or better yet, make a codesandbox.io project with a functional example of the current situation.

Comment: @Shinne Please replace `justify-content: center;` with `align-items: right; justify-content: right;` and see if it gives you your desired output